# SSH asking user password when connecting on a port

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, sshd

I have a computer C SSH reverse tunnelled to server B at port X.

Now I want to connect from computer A to computer C via B at port X.

When I do normal SSH from computer A to B as:

```
ssh -i KEYA B_USER@B_IP
```

It connects fine.

But when I do connect at port X as:

```
ssh -i KEYA B_USER@B_IP -p X
```

It asks for user password. But I have no password for B user and then it says this:
Received disconnect from B_IP at PORT X: Too many authentication failures.

I am unable to figure out a solution to this issue. It's been hours for me scratching my head. Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

SSH reverse tunnel used to connect from C to B:

```
ssh -i KEYC -f -N -R B_IP:PORT_X:localhost:22 B_USER@B_IP -o GatewayPorts=yes
```

Reverse tunnel connects fine.

Comment: Yes. Added the SSH reverse tunnel command in the edit. I am connecting to C. Using reverse ssh tunnel on C because it doesn't have a static IP. So I cannot connect directly to C from outside network. I have access to B from A. So I was doing this: A--->B<---C at port X. So I can connect via this port X.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that. I have only KEYC on C. I added public Key C on B to connect at port X. It connected. I then have KEYA on A. I added public Key A on B to connect at port X. It doesn't connect..

Answer (score 1):

After the tunnel is established everything that connects to port `X` on B is tunneled to C. The SSH server on C connects to `localhost:22` on behalf of the original connection that gets to B from wherever. Whatever listens on port `22` on C (it doesn't matter if it's `sshd` or anything else) will see the connection coming in from C.

This means when you do this on A:

```
ssh -i KEYA B_USER@B_IP -p X
```

the listening server on C sees it as if you did something like this *on C*:

```
ssh -i local_copy_of_KEYA B_USER@localhost -p 22
```

So `B_USER` and the content of `KEYA` should be recognized by the SSH server *on C*. At this point it doesn't matter whether they mean something to B or not. After the tunnel is established you should treat the address `B_IP:X` kinda like an alias for  `localhost:22` addressed from C. Except you don't have to be on C, this is the whole point of having a tunnel.

While connecting to port `X` on `B_IP` you should specify a user name valid for C and the key (or password) that authenticates this user on C.

---

To be clear: there are two *separate* SSH connections:

1. The one from C to B. It creates a tunnel from B to C. Its one end is the SSH client on C (`ssh -R …`), the other end is the SSH server on B.
2. The one from A to C. Its one end is SSH client on A, the other end is the SSH server on C. It is a single connection in the application layer (SSH), but technically there are two TCP/IP connections:

   - from A to B,
   - from C to C,

   and the tunnel in between (B to C).

   The already established tunnel connects B and C, so there's a route: A to B to C (strictly: A to B to C to C; in general it could be A to B to C to D). When it comes to TCP/IP, the SSH client on A sees (creates) the first part (A to B) and the SSH server on C sees the other part (C to C; this part is created on the fly by the `ssh` process that started the tunnel: `ssh -R …`). When it comes to SSH (different layer!), the SSH client on A and the SSH server on C are two ends of the same connection.

The important thing is the "A to C" SSH connection is just a payload transmitted via TCP/IP+tunnel+TCP/IP. The tunnel does not change anything in the application layer that is being tunneled; it just connects two networks, translates addresses and ports (compare: NAT).

The SSH client (program, `ssh`) on A and the SSH server (program, e.g. `sshd`) on C disagree on what they know about the transport layer (TCP) and the internet layer (IP); but everything that belongs to the application layer (SSH) is transmitted as-is between A and C. In particular authentication and encryption are managed solely by the SSH client on A and the SSH server on C. No end of the tunnel interferes with this payload.

Even if any end of the tunnel tried to interfere with the payload, it couldn't – because of the encryption. In case of other application protocols (where there is no encryption) the tunnel might successfully interfere; but it never does anyway, its job is to rely the payload without changing it.

For these reasons you shouldn't expect credentials that work for B to automatically work for C. B is just an end of the tunnel. As far as SSH (the application layer protocol) was concerned, the SSH connection you initiated from A engaged the SSH client on A and the SSH server on C; nothing more, nothing on B. To alter the authentication process you need to reconfigure A and/or C.

Comment: So to make this work, i need to get KEYC on computer A? Isn't there any other method?

Comment: @gapc311 Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the speedy replies... I tried to make this work by adding KEYC on A and then doing SSH, but I am getting publickey permission denied error.. Not working.. Also this way it would become more of manual work.. I am looking for a programmatic solution